# Typescript enforce function accepts first argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to enforce that a particular function accepts a first argument of a particular type

```
type MyFunc = <Args extends []>(channelId: string, ...args: Args) => string

const doThing: MyFunc = (channelId: string, arg1: number, arg2: string) => arg1 + arg2
```

I get the following error

```
Type '(channelId: string, arg1: number, arg2: string) => string' is not assignable to type 'MyFunc'.
  Types of parameters 'arg1' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'Args' is not assignable to type '[arg1: number, arg2: string]'.
      Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[arg1: number, arg2: string]'.
        Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 2.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=87#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYygXigHgIICcBzAZyggA9gJkATUgbQF0A+AClQAsBDZZCAGwCSNAFxRiwfAEtkhADRQAdMq5FiYgiQCUmZuMkzCAKCOoA9sglQaZgCodDYuEjSYo7brwHCxE6bIVVQgBGMWREAFsAIwh8QKIAJl8DWR0MPSDgqABqKCCEoA)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you'd do it, but...

Are you sure you want to concatenate a number and a string (and not use the `channelId` argument)?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYwDwAUCGAnbAtgM5QQAewEyAJibhNtQPbIA2IUKA1skwO7IA2gF0AfFAC8UABSoAFtmTIIrAJLUAXFCLBcAS2QBzADRQAdBbB5CRLTnzEAlJPE79RgNwAoL6hY6oZgAVOQNDLTgkNHRBZC1kRAIAIwhcUzctNzCxSRl5RWU1alM8QwBGEtxDACZnCXFSsqgAaihS6u9ff2AoeiJEVh6pYNCjaQByAhAAfXylFWm9anHTABZq03G5FVYmKD4mXFZlx28-ZCImVggzXcNpPoHgZwB6F6gAInXt1l39w+OHy8QA)

```ts
type MyFunc<Params extends readonly unknown[]> = (channelId: string, ...params: Params) => string;

const doThing: MyFunc<[n: number, str: string]> = (channelId, arg1, arg2) => arg1 + arg2;

const result = doThing('my_channel_id', 42, 'hello world');
console.log(result) // "42hello world"
```

Comment: Oh you can ignore the implementation it's just an example, thanks!

Comment: @david_adler So this answered the question?

Comment: still checking, as I might need to infer the generic parameter you've statically set so will circle back to the answer

Comment: If it turns out that I misunderstood a detail in the question, just let me know.